# Interpolation error to generate a two variable function

Tags: function-construction, fitting, interpolation, variable-definitions, data-format

[image]

I am facing some issues with performing an interpolation. From the image, you can find the values in three columns, the 1st column is `x`, the second column is `y` and the third column is `F`. I want to find a function, `F(x, y)` with `Interpolation`. But the interpolation is not working correctly. Most of the time, I get negative or wrong values if the input value lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.
[This is the link of my data file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fgDBIyTQP7RGgcph2cU7ChvrMyD-dRQm/view?usp=sharing)

Here is what I tried:

```
data1 = Import["source.dat", "Table"]; (*I stored the data in .dat file*)
x = data1[[All, 1]]; y = data1[[All, 2]]; F = data1[[All, 3]]; (*Assigning the value of x, y, F*)

F1 = Interpolation[Transpose[{x, y, F}], InterpolationOrder -> 1]; (*Interpolation*) 

F2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := F1[x, y]; (*wrote it as a function of x and y as later I will use it for another purpose*)
```

I have tried to change the `InterpolationOrder -> 1` to `All`, but it does not solve the issue. Most of the time I get wrong values from interpolation. I am calling interpolation with `F1[x, y]`. Help me with ideas to solve the issue.
I am using Mathematica v12 and v13.

Comment: "I get negative or wrong values if the input value lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function" <- this is your problem. Interpolation gives you a function that works only on a specific domain.

Comment: "Most of the time I am getting the wrong values from interpolation." Maybe you can provide specific inputs that are giving you wrong results (and why you think the results are wrong).

Comment: @lericr  For example, F1[0.1, 10^-30], I am getting the value "-4.61896*10^38" with this warning message, "Input value lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.".  I am not supposed to get any negative value.

Comment: Well, 10^-30 is outside of the range of data for the y values. Like the warning message says.

Comment: But, I am also getting a negative value for this case, F1[0.1, 3*10^-44] = -3.23547*10^31 with the same warning. But, if you check the table, you can find that 3*10^-44 should be in the range of the 2nd column.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at the shape of your data, I'm not really sure what Interpolation should be expected to do. To my eye, that point does look problematic, but I'm not really sure what Interpolation is actually doing with the data you gave it.

Comment: If you perform `ListPointPlot3D[data1]`, you'll (hopefully) see the reason for the "odd" performance.

Answer (score 1):

You won't have much luck attempting to use interpolation using both $X$ and $Y$ with any software package.  Here is a plot of your data:

```
data1 = Import["source.dat", "Table"];
data1 = data1[[2 ;;]];
ListPointPlot3D[data1, SphericalRegion -> True, RotationAction -> "Clip",
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 18, Bold, Black] &) /@ {"X", "Y", "F"}, ImagePadding -> 50]
```

[image: 3D plot of data]

Given that for a given $X$ there is only small range of values of $Y$ and for a given $Y$ there is only a small range of values of $X$, one should not expect justifiable results from most of the possible $(X,Y)$.  In short, there's only data available for a small subset of $X$ and $Y$ values.